# How align paragraph with labels before resume enumitem list

Tags: enumitem, lengths, calc

I have an enumerate list created with `enumitem` that I interrupt and then resume. Between the last item before the interruption and the first after the resumption, I insert a text paragraph. How can I horizontally align that paragraph so that:

1. The first line of that paragraph is horizontally aligned with the *left* ends of the item labels (as indicated on the output shown at the end here); and instead
2. The entire paragraph's left edge is aligned with the *left* ends of the item labels.

Here's what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*), ref={\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is a list.

\begin{myenum}
  \item
    One
  \item
    Two
\end{myenum}

\hspace{\the\labelindent}%
Some other text will go here that may or may not fill out more than a single line of text on the page.

\begin{myenum}[resume*]
  \item 
    Three
  \item
    Four
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired alignment of intermediate paragraph.]

I believe I want some arithmetic combination of lengths, such as in...

```
\hspace{\the\labelwidth-\the\labelsep}
```

...and I would expect to use some command from package `calc` to do this, but: (a) I don't know how to combine such lengths; and (b) I don't see just what lengths I need to combine.

Comment: `\parindent\labelsep\hangindent\labelsep` Some other text ...

Comment: Semantically, I would rather align the labels on the left margin with the `wide` option.

Comment: If you mean to add the `wide` option to the `\setlist{myenum,1}`, then in the `resume`d part of the list, the labels are no longer aligned with those in the first part of the list.

Comment: @Fran: With `\parindent\labelsep\hangindent\labelsep`, the `some other text` is *not* aligned with the left parens of the labels, but a bit to the left of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to do the job:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*), ref={\arabic*}}

\newdimen\midlistindent
\settowidth{\midlistindent}{(1)\kern-\labelindent\kern-\labelsep}
\newcommand{\midlist}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \leftskip\midlistindent
  \noindent #1\unskip\par
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is a list.

\begin{myenum}
  \item
    One
  \item
    Two
\end{myenum}

\midlist{%
Some other text will go here that may or may not fill out more than a single line of text on the page.
}

\begin{myenum}[resume*]
  \item 
    Three
  \item
    Four
\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Is there some strictly LaTeX way to do this?

Comment: @murray -- there's not a "direct" way to do this.  i looked into the `enumitem` code to see how `\labelwidth` was calculated, but it is far from obvious.  so i simply took advantage of the existence of the `\labelwidth` name, to avoid having to descend into the realm of command names with `@` in them.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea! However, instead of using the `calc` environment, `enumitem` can handle it on its own. For reference, here's the dimensions figure in the `enumitem` package documentation:

[image]

It appears you wish to have the left margin set to zero, and the label width equal to the item indent.

This is achieved with the following adjustments to the `enumerate` environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}[
    align=left, 
    leftmargin=0pt, 
    itemindent=\labelwidth, 
    labelsep=0pt
]
\end{enumerate}
```

This looks like so in your document. Is this what you were after?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*), ref={\arabic*},
    align=left, 
    leftmargin=0pt, 
    itemindent=\labelwidth, 
    labelsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

    \noindent Here is a list.
    
    \begin{myenum}
      \item One
      \item Two
    \end{myenum}
    
    \noindent Some other text will go here that may or may not fill out more than a single line of text on the page.
    
    \begin{myenum}[resume*]
      \item Three
      \item Four
    \end{myenum}

\end{document}
```